# Cannot get form from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jaunt-api

I am trying to get the login form from:

https://www.etoro.com/login

when I inspect in Chrome I can see the  element, however when I use the jaunt api in Java I cannot get the form.

```
userAgent = new UserAgent();
userAgent.visit("https://etoro.com/login");
List<Form> forms = userAgent.doc.getForms();
System.out.println(forms.size()); // 0
```

I have little experience in HTML so any direction would be great!

This is my first post so if I havent done something correctly please let me know.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are out of luck with a simple Java web scraper.

If you look at the source of the page in the browser, you see, that the page consists mainly of a long `<script>`. The whole login form is then created by the browser with Javascript.

If you absolutely must scrape this exact form, you need a tool, that can execute Javascript. For this, you could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). That's basically a complete browser, that can be controlled with a Javascript API.

Search Google for `phantomjs web scraping` to get you started.